# Use PouchDB with angular 5 or 6

Tags: angular5, angular6, pouchdb

How can I add PouchDB to an Angular 5 or 6 project? I am using Angular 6 and I could not find any way to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can use PouchDB with angular with this **[`library`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/pouchdb)**

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
```

Here is a sample **[`Poucdhb with angular`](https://github.com/sajeetharan/Angular-PouchDB-Cloudant)** project i came across.

You can use it as follows,

```
  private db: any;
  private isInstantiated: boolean;
  private listener: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  public constructor() {

    if (!this.isInstantiated) {
      this.db = new PouchDB('locosporalva');
      this.isInstantiated = true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: we need also to add (window as any).global = window; in polyfills.ts file

Comment: `(window as any).global = window;` is needed to resolve `global is not defined` error upon startup